# Replace .EntireRow.Copy with a way of only copying certain rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a vba to copy and paste rows from one worksheet to another when a specific value is entered into a cell within range "O".

At present my vba works fine, however **I want it to copy from column A through to Z as opposed to the entire row.**

Please see below my current code:

```
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
I = Worksheets("Demand Log").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Change Log").Cells(Worksheets("Change Log").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
If J = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Change Log").Range) = 0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Demand Log").Range("O5:O" & I)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Change Team" Then
    J = J + 1
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Change Log").Range("A" & J)
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting rows you want to work from the bottom up.

And you can use Intersect:

```
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
I = Worksheets("Demand Log").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Change Log").Cells(Worksheets("Change Log").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
If J = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Change Log").Range) = 0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Demand Log").Range("O5:O" & I)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = xRg.Count To 1 Step -1
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Change Team" Then
        J = J + 1
        With Worksheets("Demand Log")
            Intersect(.Rows(xRg(K).Row), .Range("A:Z")).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Change Log").Range("A" & J)
            Intersect(.Rows(xRg(K).Row), .Range("A:Z")).Delete xlShiftUp
        End With
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Scott Craner - Unfortunately the amended code you provided is only copying values in column "O" and then pasting them into column B with all other values disappearing without pasting. Appreciate the time taken to advise though, thanks.

Comment: Try the latest,  I have changed it again to include the whole range.  I forgot the whole row in the intersect and was only using the one cell.  It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Resize method. By the way, when deleting rows always loop backwards as otherwise you will miss rows.

```
Cells(xRg(K).row,1).Resize(,26).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Change Log").Range("A" & J)
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure how to loop backwards, that was going to be the next question.

Comment: See Scott's answer for that.